# TypoScript / Typo3 : How to use | to set the value more than once in the same wrapper?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

How to put the same value inside `<a href="#{thisValue}">{againTheSameValue}</a>` for the menu in TypoScript? I want the same value for both text of a-tag and href-value:

> [eg: `<a href="#home">Home</a>`]

Here's my TypoScript:

```
lib.mainmenu = HMENU
lib.mainmenu {
    entryLevel = 0
    1 = TMENU
    1{
        wrap = <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> | </ul>
        noBlur = 1
        NO = 1
        NO {
            #
            # I want the href too have the same value as set by "|" for it's text
            #
            wrapItemAndSub = <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">|</a></li>
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
            ATagTitle.field = title
            ATagParams = class="page-scroll"
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play around with stdWrap and *field:...*:

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#{field:title}">|</a></li>
wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
```

In case you want to manipulate your *href* attribute (e.g. make it lowercase), the code must be written the other way round:

```
wrapItemAndSub = <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#|">{field:title}</a></li>
wrapItemAndSub.insertData = 1
stdWrap.case = lower
```

As you see, you can't apply stdWrap to *{field:...}*, but you can swap positions in *wrapItemAndSub* and apply stdWrap to a menu item text.

Tested both variants under 7.3 - works.

Comment: Perfect! Worked under 6.2.14 as well and exactly like how I wanted it to be.  
Do you also have a hint for me how to make only that `{field:title}` into lowercase?

Comment: @Ren, I've updated my answer with an example, which should fit to your purposes.

Comment: This was very helpful.